# ffmpeg png overlay to mp4 color is not correct

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay some subs on an .mp4 file using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i count5.mp4 -i subs1.png -i subs2.png \
-filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=enable=between(t\,1\,2):x=0:y=0[out]; \
[out][2]overlay=enable=between(t\,3.5\,4.6):x=0:y=0[out]" \
-map [out] -map 0:a? new.mp4
```

It works, but the subtitle colors are not correct:
Here is the overlay:

[image]

Here is how it looks on the .mp4 output:

[image]

Looks like it turned a little pink or orange. Maybe the better question is how do I maintain the correct video quality? I have very limited knowledge of video formats and ffmpeg so not sure where to start debugging or the right keywords to use.

Finder tells me the png is color profile `sRGB IEC61966-2.1` and the video is `HD (1-1-1)`